# how to implement concat_ws with apache pig

Tags: hive, apache-pig

In apache hive, we can do concatenation like this:

```
concat_ws('-', split('1_2_3', '_'))     --result '1-2-3'


concat_ws('seperate-string', tuple-like-data-structure)
```

I wonder, how can implement concate_ws in apache pig ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested too, my way is pretty ugly but should work I think:

```
CONCAT
    (
        STRSPLIT('1_2_3', '_').$0,
        '-',
        STRSPLIT('1_2_3', '_').$1,
        '-',
        STRSPLIT('1_2_3', '_').$2,
    )
```

But if it's this case specifically, then REPLACE('1_2_3', '_', '-') would probably work fine..